# VNC: one session per user, recoverable

Tags: vnc, x11, xrdp

I know how to use VNC as a single user to see what's on the screen (possibly even the login screen, out of the Window Manager). If the vnc server crashes, no big deal, launch it again, restart your client and keep working.

I also know how to have vncserver start a user-dependant session when it starts (have the line /etc/X11/Xsession in ~/.vnc/xstartup); but the problem is that if the VNC server crashes (and it happens regularly), you lose every program you were running in your session.

I would like the following features:

- Machine has multiple users, each should have his own session (possibly using different window managers)
- If the vnc server crashes, they can simply restart it and connect again, TO THE SAME SESSION as before, not losing any work.
- Bonus points if multiple simultaneous accesses to the same session are possible

How can I configure this? If not VNC, are there better tools for this? X2go, Xrdp, etc.?

Comment: Sun's `uttsc` RDP client had/has something like that, it was used for their virtual infrastructure Sun Ray (true roaming of live sessions over different Thin Clients). You may find something in the space of VDI.